# Emulating row_number when querying a view significantly effects performance

Tags: mysql

I need a `row_number` field on result query when querying a View.

Somehow the query takes a huge amount of time to run compared to querying the same view.

Without `row_number` it takes around 200ms and with `row_number` it takes 30s to run.

Our DB version does not support `ROW_NUMBER()` syntax. So I am currently implementing the same functionality with

```sql
(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS row_number
```

The query I'm trying to run

```sql
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT *, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS row_number FROM some_view;
```

View definition

```sql
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `user`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `some_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `some_table`.`field1` AS `field1`,
        `some_table`.`field2` AS `field2`,
        `some_table`.`field3` AS `field3`,
        `some_table`.`field4` AS `field4`,
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(`some_table`.`json_data`,'$.field5') AS SIGNED) AS `field5`,
        JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`some_table`.`json_data`, '$.field6')) AS `field6`,
        JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`some_table`.`json_data`, '$.field7')) AS `field7`,
        JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`some_table`.`json_data`,'$.field8.name')) AS `field8`
    FROM
        `some_table`
```

expected to get a reasonable runtime for this query

Comment: Generate a `ROW_NUMBER()`  with a self join  ? `SELECT ..., COUNT(*) LEFT JOIN ...  ON ... < .... GROUP BY ... `  .. Also we need table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`) for every table involved in the question to make suggestions also we need to know the VIEW defined query..

Comment: Simple; don't use Views. They serve almost no useful purpose in MySQL

Comment: @RaymondNijland i don't want to use extra nested select and group by, this is a very large Table and will affect performance.

Comment: Try to recreate the view with `ALGORITHM = MERGE` , as it does matter [View Processing Algorithms](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html)

Comment: *" this is a very large Table and will affect performance."*  Define very large as MySQL is perfect able to handle millions or even in the billions off records just fine when having indexes.. Also without all table structures we still can't give better suggestions..

Comment: @RaymondNijland
It sure can. But as you said, when using it right (means creating indexes) i don't see extra nested select and group by as the right use.

Comment: *" i don't see extra nested select and group by as the right use."* Using a nested select (delivered table) and GROUP BY are really not from the SQL devil.. Also you should still be providing **all** tables structures see mine first comment if you want better answers as for right now this question has to limited information to suggest annything "beter".. Also did you try recreating the VIEW with `ALGORITHM = MERGE` ?